# How to create an incidence matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to create

```
[[ 1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [-1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  1,  0],
 [ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  1],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1]]

S=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
D=[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]
INC = [[0]*len(D) for _ in range(len(S))]

for i in range(len(D)):
```

after this I am doing something wrong to where I just get a matrix of zeros

```
    for j in S:
        if i == j:
            INC.append(1)
```

I have tried spiting D into two different lists and it started to get to complicated for me

```
my_list1 = [i[0] for i in D]
my_list2 = [i[1] for i in D]
```

Comment: Is there a pattern to this incidence matrix?  It might help us think of an answer if there's a pattern to it.  I'm not sure I understand how to make it.

Comment: What do you want? A matrix of {+1, 0, -1}'s given two lists of coordinates you want to be +/-1?

Answer (score 7):

My best guess of what you want...your variable names are pretty poor. I'd use [NetworkX (`networkx`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx) and let it do all the math.

```
import networkx as nx

nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
edges = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 6]]

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

incidence_matrix = -nx.incidence_matrix(G, oriented=True) 
# ^ this returns a scipy sparse matrix, can convert into the full array as below
# (as long as your node count is reasonable: this'll have that squared elements)
print(incidence_matrix.toarray())
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0. -1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0. -1. -1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0. -1.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1. -1.]]
```

Comment: How would you handle weights?

Comment: The weights can be parameters assigned to the each edge as in `G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=3)` which assigns a weight equal to 3 to the edge between the nodes 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is merely an alternate approach that differs from your version, but you can use it as inspiration. I believe you should read about [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Anyway... This is my take on your incidence matrix:

```
rows = 6
cols = 9
ones = [[0,1,2], [0,4,5], [1,3,5,6], [4,5,7], [3,6,8], [7, 8]]

INC = [ [ 0 for i in xrange(cols) ] for j in xrange(rows) ]

for i,row in enumerate(ones):
    for col in row:
        INC[i][col] = 1

[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Note that I am operating on rows, not columns as I suspect you are doing.
Insert '-1' by making the values in "edges" +/- and use if -, elif +, else pass if you want to implement this version.

**In Python3** `xrange` must be changed to `range`