# Python NetworkX creating graph from incidence matrix

Tags: python, networkx

I have an incidence matrix (where the rows are nodes and the columns are edges) as follows (it is read from a text file into a NumPy array):

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I would like to create a graph using NetworkX from this matrix, but could not find how to do that. NetworkX [from_numpy_matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html) works only with adjacency matrices. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549762/how-to-create-an-incidence-matrix) is a good example of how to create an incidence matrix using NetworkX (but that's not my case, because I have already an incidence matrix to begin with). I have also tried [this](https://dschult-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/networkx/convert_matrix.html), but got the nasty error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\convert.py", line 150, in to_networkx_graph
    "Input is not a correct numpy matrix or array.")
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Input is not a correct numpy matrix or array.
```

Looks a simple question, but perhaps it isn't. Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Networkx has a handy [`nx.from_numpy_matrix` function](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html) taking an adjacency matrix, so once we convert the incidence matrix to an adjacency matrix, we're good.

Say we start with the incidence matrix

```
im = np.array([[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
```

To convert it to an adjacency matrix, first let's see which nodes are connected:

```
am = (np.dot(im, im.T) > 0).astype(int)
```

Here we're just checking if any two nodes have at least one edge between them.

If you want to remove self loops, you can call

```
np.fill_diagonal(am, 0)
```

Let's see now `am`:

```
>>> am
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

To create the graph, now we can just call

```
networkx.from_numpy_matrix(am)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ami Tavory! I works quite well. The trick of transposing the original matrix to create an adjacency matrix is very nice. Best wishes.